# Javascript issue- Cannot Submit form after document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, php, html, textbox

```
document.getElementById("hs-search-origin").value = myloc;
```

I am successfully writing the value in a Text Box

The text box is attached to a searchbox and up on clicking the search button,  search is not happening.
I have to edit the textbox, like remove character or add character in the text box, to make it work.

For Ex:

```
myloc="i love stackoverflow";
document.getElementById("hs-search-origin").value = myloc;
```

The text box shows the value i.e "i love stackoverflow" but on clicking the button, nothing happens.

I have to either edit the text in the textbox and then click on search to make it work. What is the issue, any guess

Comment: If you put down your code will be better, btw you can use onchange in the input "box" to re run the serach function every time the value inside the input change

Comment: @FrancescoFortin — The change event won't fire if the change is caused by the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have some code which runs (and does a search) when the user changes the value of the text box.

It doesn't run when you change the value with JavaScript.

You need to call that code explicitly when you want it to fire in response to something else than the user typing.